# Trying to play video using MPMoviePlayerController, only get audio

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to play a video in my iPhone app. I used this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *movieUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:
                       [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Myvideo" 
                                                       ofType:@"mp4"]];

    //create a new instance of MPMoviePlayerController
    MPMoviePlayerController* myMovie=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] 
                                      initWithContentURL:movieUrl];

    //disable scaling of our movie
    myMovie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeNone;

    //don't show any controls
   // myMovie.movieControlMode = MPMovieControlModeHidden;

    //you can specify at which time the movie should 
    //start playing (default is 0.0)
    myMovie.initialPlaybackTime = 2.0;

    //register a callback method which will be called
    //after the movie finished
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(movieFinished:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                               object:myMovie]; 

    //start the movie (asynchronous method)
    [myMovie play];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

Only the sound works with this code. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to allocate a frame to your movie and add it to the view. See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

So you can add:

```
[myMoview.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's
[self.view addSubview:myMovie.view];
```

Comment: Thank you but i don't understand what is myView ?

Comment: I gave it as a snippet. this is the view of your viewController. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Josh Can i add the controls ? play , stop ... ?

Answer (score 5):

## [Apple Technical Q&A 1240](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1240/_index.html):

> ### MPMoviePlayerController plays movie audio but not video
>
> **Q:**  I'm able to successfully play movies using `MPMoviePlayerController` on iOS 3.1.3. When I run this same code on the iPad and on the iPhone with iOS 4 I can hear the movie audio, but the video is no longer displayed. What's going on?
>
> **A:** Starting with iPhone iOS 3.2, calling the `-play:` method still starts playback of the movie but it does not ensure that the movie is visible. In order to display a movie, you must get the new view property from your `MPMoviePlayerController` object and add that view to your view hierarchy. Here's a code snippet:
>
> **Listing 1**  How to add the MPMoviePlayerController view property to your view hierarchy to play a movie.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
[[player view] setFrame:[myView bounds]]; // size to fit parent view exactly
[myView addSubview:[player view]];
[player play];
```

> See [Important Porting Tip for Using the Media Player Framework](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/StartingYourProject/StartingYourProject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009370-CH9-SW10) and the [MPMoviePlayerController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html) for more information.